# Thread race condition and passing by value in C

Tags: c, sockets, thread-safety

I can't quite figure out why this simple network code prevents a race condition

```
int main(void) {
   ...
   listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);

     for(;;) {
              pthread_t t; int *socket;

              socket = malloc(sizeof(int));
              *socket = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);

              pthread_create(&t, NULL, service_request, socket);
              pthread_detached(&t);
     }
  ...
}
```

the explanation I was given is that the socket descriptor value has to be allocated in the heap to avoid a race condition where another accept overrides its value. What I don't understand is why. What if I just wrote:

```
int main(void) {
   ...
   listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);

     for(;;) {
              pthread_t t; int socket;

              socket = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);

              pthread_create(&t, NULL, service_request, socket);
              pthread_detached(&t);
     }
  ...
}
```

where I pass the socket descriptor "socket" by value. The next accept will anyway happen after `pthread_create()` has already been called and the value of "socket" copied, in another iteration of the for loop.

Now I'm not sure whether the value is copied when the procedure `pthread_create()` is called within the `main()`, or in another moment. In this second case I would understand the race condition.

Comment: "*the value is copied when the procedure pthread_create() is called within the main()*" yes, it (the value *passed*) is.

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_create()` passes a pointer argument to the start routine. You simply pass an integer. Therefore you assume, that the filedescriptor integer can be (implicitly) casted to a pointer value and back without corruption. This is probably true since filedescriptors are often below 16-bit and pointer values are usually >= 16-bit in size, but it is still ugly and error-prone.

So the `malloc()`-version is to prefer as the first example shows.

What they meant with "race condition" is this version:

```
 for(;;) {
          pthread_t t; int socket;

          socket = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);

          pthread_create(&t, NULL, service_request, &socket);
          pthread_detached(&t);
 }
```

Here the start routine had to evaluate the filedescriptor value *before* the next accept happens. Otherwise, the old value is overwritten and cannot be used any more.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, you don't need to dynamcially allocate (using e.g. `malloc`) the value to pass.

***However*** the thread functions (and the `pthread_create`) accepts a *pointer* and not a value, and this is the cause of most problems as many simply use the address-of operator `&` to pass a pointer to the variable:

```
pthread_create(&t, NULL, service_request, &socket);
```

This can indeed lead to race-conditions as the value of `socket` might have change before the thread function dereference the pointer and uses the value.

But for simple integers (like the `socket` variable in your example) there is a simple workaround that doesn't include using `malloc`: Casting the value to a pointer. This is actually one of the very few occasions where it's considered okay to do such casting:

```
pthread_create(&t, NULL, service_request, (void *) (intptr_t) socket);
```

In the thread function you do the opposite cast:

```
void *service_request(void *pointer)
{
    int socket = (int) (intptr_t) pointer;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm doubtful that the double cast in fact achieves anything useful here.  You need [`u`]`intptr_t` for safe pointer -> integer -> pointer round-tripping, but as far as I can see, it doesn't help (nor hurt) for the integer -> pointer -> integer case.  The latter case has implementation-defined behavior regardless.

Comment: Nitpicking: Using `(u)intptr_t` for conversion of a pointer's value is only guaranteed to work for converting pointer-value->`(u)intptr_t`->pointer-value, but not for: `(u)intptr_t`->pointer-value->`(u)intptr_t`.